# Loading console script using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script loading a page from determined URL address - I put that script into console of a browser and it loads the JS when I submit a piece of code.

Is there a way of creating a form with a textarea where user can submit his URL address and it will load the code I put into browser console with his submitted URL? If yes, could you point me to some documentation/tutorials about it? I am not sure how it's called and would love to get some knowledge about it. Thanks!

Comment: A bit more detail about what you're trying to do, or an example of it, would help here. However, it sounds like this won't work due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I do have an extension to a web application that loads in a separate iframe in the web app. I want to load a proper URL in that iframe based on what the user submits. I do have an API method that allows it: 

`App.collections.Integrations.add({
  id: 'sandbox',
  url: '$submitted_url_here'
})`

Comment: Of course the URL has to be https:// as the web app, http:// won't work, just trying to figure out how can I make a code that allows passing URL as value to this method and running this method on click.